# Electron auto-updater not relaunching the app

Tags: macos, electron

I am trying to set auto update in my electron mac app.
I am using the following code:

```
const autoUpdater = electron.autoUpdater;

autoUpdater.setFeedURL('https://server_url?v=' + appVersion);

autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();

autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', function(){

    autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();

});
```

But I think this statement `autoUpdater.quitAndInstall()` is not working. The app is not getting quit and relaunching. But if I manually quit the app and reopen, it opens the updated app.
In the app I have a window which is not closable. Is that causing the issue here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The non-closable window was causing the issue. I got the solution from electron documentation itself. I used the following code to solve the issue:

```
autoUpdater.on('update-downloaded', function(){

    mainWindow.setClosable(true);
    autoUpdater.quitAndInstall();

});
```

Comment: I still have the same problem. I added the setClosable one but it did not help.